# Double pointer constructor for C++ web service

Tags: c++, soap

I have a web service with the following method:

```
int ns__bidReceived(int transact, std::string datetime, double watts, double timespan, double tariffHigh, double timeout, double *result, double *tariffPaid);
```

When a client sends a message to the server, both the **result** and **tariffPaid** variables are set in the server to be returned to the client. When I only have **result** (thus, no tariffPaid vairable) it sets it fine. If both **result** and **tariffPaid** are present, **tariffPaid** is set fine, but **result** goes haywire (sets to -0.0000000 when it should set to 1). Other operations continue normally.

Does anyone know why that happens?
I use SOAP and the gSOAP tool to generate web service framework.

Comment: What do you mean with "If both result and tariffPaid are present" is there a second function of the same name but with a different signature or is there a default argument (NULL ?) for the last pointer ?

Comment: If I put both variables as pointers in that function. That is the only function that is present.

Comment: So how do you communicate that a variable is supposed to be not set ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? you pass pointers to two variables, if they are set in the function their values change and if they are not set their values remain the same as before they were passed?

Comment: @CornelVester Mea culpa. Took me a while. I'm afraid the bug is hidden in the ns__bidReceived function. Which version if gSOAP do you use. In the current 2.8.x branch I find a lot uf functions with the ns__ prefix but no  ns__bidReceived...